# How can I shift columns of numpy array so that the first two colums go to the last and the last two come to the first?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a numpy array. lets say

```
x=([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,12,13])
x2 = np.reshape(x, (2,6))
```

now

```
x2= [[ 8  9  0  1  2  3]
     [ 4  5  6  7 12 13]]
```

I need to shift x2 in such a way that the final result be

```
X3=[[2  3   0  1  8   9]
    [12 13  6  7  4   5]]
```

Comment: did you try anything yet? did you look at the e.g., `hstack` and `vstack` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fancy index and swap

```
x2[:, 0:2], x2[:, -2:] = x2[:, -2:].copy(), x2[:, 0:2].copy()

Out[117]:
array([[ 2,  3,  0,  1,  8,  9],
       [12, 13,  6,  7,  4,  5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy anything; just slice once and pass both lists of indices.

```
import numpy as np


x = np.array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13])
x = x.reshape(x, [2, 6])
x = x[:, [[0, -2], [1, -1]]] = x[:, [[-2, 0], [-1, 1]]]
x

# array([
#   [ 2,  3,  0,  1,  8,  9],
#   [12, 13,  6,  7,  4,  5],
# ])
```

I noticed you had a tensorflow tag on your question.  This is a bit more involved in tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.constant([
    [8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13],
])

idx = tf.constant([
    [[0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 0], [0, 1]],
    [[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 0], [1, 1]],
])

shp = tf.constant([2, 6])

swapped = tf.scatter_nd(indices=idx, updates=x, shape=shp)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(swapped.eval(session=sess))

# [[ 2  3  0  1  8  9]
#  [12 13  6  7  4  5]]
```

Comment: Actually, I am working with TensorFlow but its array problem. I have 361 arrays of shape(39*200) and I want to shift the first 45 columns to the last and the last one to the first.